# Are there implications with destructuring getState() (in a Redux Think) as opposed to calling it many times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-thunk

Are there any implications when destructuring `getState()` in a Redux thunk?

I find that it's much more readable to do something like `const {bar, foo} = getState().app` as opposed to `getState().app.bar` and `getState().app.foo` everywhere.

Is there an argument (or proof rather) that it's actually cheaper doing a variable assignment or calling the `getState()` function multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

No perf implications.

`getState`'s implementation is just `return currentState`.

Personally, I'd only call it once in a given function just because there's no benefit to calling it more than once.